# PostgreSQL count other values of ID that have the same value of other column

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count

Let's say we have the following table that stores `id` of an observation and its `address_id`. You can create the table with the following code:

```
drop table if exists schema.pl_address_cnt;
create table schema.pl_address_cnt (
    id serial,
    address_id int);

insert into schema.pl_address_cnt(address_id) values 
(100), (101), (100), (101), (100), (125), (128), (200), (200), (100);
```

My task is to count for each `id` how many other `id`s (thus -1) have the same `address_id`. I've come up with a solution that turns out to be quite expensive (`explain`) on the original dataset. I wonder whether my solution can be somehow optimised.

```
with tmp_table as (select address_id
                        , count(distinct id) as id_count
                    from schema.pl_address_cnt
                    group by address_id
)
select id
    , id_count - 1
from schema.pl_address_cnt as pac
left join tmp_table as tt on tt.address_id=pac.address_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to omit the CTE and do a self left join on common address but different ID and then aggregate this.

```
SELECT pac1.id,
       count(pac2.id)
       FROM pl_address_cnt pac1
            LEFT JOIN pl_address_cnt pac2
                      ON pac1.address_id = pac2.address_id
                         AND pac1.id <> pac2.id
       GROUP BY pac1.id
       ORDER BY pac1.id;
```

For performance you can try indexes on `(address_id, id)` and `(id)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. While I omit the CTE and use your solution `explain analyse` returns 3x the cost of my original query :(